# Getting strange warnings in my CXF JAX-RS web service logs

Tags: web-services, servlets, cxf

I have few JAX-RS web services built on Apache CXF running on Tomcat. The host machine runs Ubuntu on DigitalOcean cloud infrastructure. The services are published on address: ip:8080/appserv/<------------------>

In the logs, I get to see strange warnings; Logs are just full of these warnings. I am not sure where does these **zc.qq.com** coming from?

Wondering how can these requests even hit my server?

```
WARN  org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController - Can't find the the request for http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init's Observer
```

I  didn't find any help on internet. People are getting similar warnings but the url in the warning message is their own.

Answer (score 0):

QQ is kinda search and news portal in chinaaa, but no one knows what is going on behind it!

I think, they are:

Dear artificial, full-free-time, and dreaming hackers.

Just try to keep your stuffs secure(`not to be an artificial coder to not be hacked by an artificial hacker`) and ignore all of these, I get too much from them too, you are not alone.